# Creating luigi parameters from other parameters at initialization

Tags: python, luigi

I have the following question - can I use the value of one parameter to define another parameter ? Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to do.
Suppose I have a config file that looks like this:

```
[MyTaskRunner]
logdir=/tmp/logs
numruns=2
```

and I defined `MyTaskRunner` like this:

```
class MyTaskRunner(luigi.Task):
      logdir=luigi.Parameter(default=None)
      rundate=luigi.Parameter(default=today)
```

where logdir is a parameter obtained from the config file and rundate is a parameter that was passed in at runtime.

Now, suppose I wish to define a new variable `logpath_str` like this

```
       logpath_str="{}/{}".format(logdir, rundate)
```

Is it possible to define this as a parameter ?

Would the solution be to specify the default value as in:

```
       logpath=luigi.Parameter(default=logpath_str)
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Parameter values are not resolved until the class has been initialised (during `__init__`) so a simple way to achieve the behaviour you're looking for is to implement `__init__` yourslef and initialise `logpath` with a default value after calling super.

```
class MyTaskRunner(luigi.Task):
    logdir=luigi.Parameter(default=None)
    logpath=luigi.Parameter(default=None)
    rundate=luigi.Parameter(default=today)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTaskRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.logpath is None:
            self.logpath = "{}/{}".format(self.logdir, self.rundate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator for this.

```py
class MyTaskRunner(luigi.Task):
      logdir=luigi.Parameter(default=None)
      rundate=luigi.Parameter(default=today)

      @property
      def logpath_str():
          return "{}/{}".format(self.logdir, self.rundate)
```

When the property is called, the object is already instantiated and the two necessary variables are initialized and hence properly callable.

Compared to overriding the constructor, you save some unnecessary lines of code. And, personally, I think the intention is more clear.

However, this only works as long as your parameter (here `logpath_str`) has to be read-only. As soon as the parameter has to be writable, you have to override `__init__`. Hence, in this case, it may be better to go with [Michael C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001242/7504509)'s solution.

For completeness, with a setter, the solution would look like this:

```py
class MyTaskRunner(luigi.Task):
    logdir=luigi.Parameter(default=None)
    rundate=luigi.Parameter(default=today)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the default here
        self._logpath_str = "{}/{}".format(self.logdir, self.rundate)

    @property
    def logpath_str():
        return self._logpath_str

    @logpath_str.setter
    def logpath_str(value):
        self._logpath_str = value
```